# predict.lars command for lasso regression: what are the "s" and "p" parameters?

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction, lasso-regression

In `help(predict.lars)` we can read that the parameter `s` is "a value, or vector of values, indexing the path. Its values depends on the mode= argument. By default (mode="step"), s should take on values between 0 and p (e.g., a step of 1.3 means .3 of the way between step 1 and 2.)"

**What does "indexing the path" mean?** Also, `s` must take a value between 1 and `p`, but **what is `p`?** The parameter `p` is not mentioned elsewhere in the help file.

I know this is basic, but there is not a single question up on SO about `predict.lars`.

Comment: Questions like "what does this statistical parameter mean" are probably best suited to CrossValidated; this isn't a programming problem which is what SO is for.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting statistical results.

Comment: @HongOoi The question is about R programming, not stats. I want to know how to use a command and the help file is unclear. The command calls for `p` input but doesn't tell the reader what that is. That's an R question. @Thomas The question is not about *interpreting* results.

Answer (score 3):

**It is easiest to use the `mode="norm"` option. In this case, `s` should just be your L1-regularization coefficient (`\lambda`).**

To understand `mode=step`, you need to know a little more about the LARS algorithm.

One problem that LARS can solve is the L1-regularized regression problem: `min ||y-Xw||^2+\lambda|w|`, where `y` are the outputs, `X` is a matrix of input vectors, and `w` are the regression weights.

A simplified explanation of how LARS works is that it greedily builds a solution to this problem by adding or removing dimensions from the regression weight vector.

Each of these greedy steps can be interpreted as a solution to a L1 regularized problem with decreasing values of `\lambda`. The sequence of these steps is known as the path.

So, given the LARS path, to get the solution for a user-supplied `\lambda`, you iterate along the path until the next element is less than the input `\lambda`, then you take a partial step  (`\lambda` decreases linearly between each step).